# How to divide string using a regular expression?

Tags: c#, regex, replace

I want to know how to split this string using regex.

```
String Temp = "EHP50-TS Spectrum  04-01-10  02:47 Narda Safety Test Solutions"
```

I want to separate the above string to the group name and value.

```
Group    Value
Date     04-01-10
time     02:47
```

If anyone knows how to convert the above string to regex, please leave answer.

Everybody have a nice day!

Comment: what is `Group Name` and `Value`

Comment: Did you try to google and learn regex? SO shouldnt write your code for you. If you try to write the regex and it fails, then you have a specific problem needing a solution. Currently you have a service request.

Answer (score 2):

```
string Temp = "EHP50-TS Spectrum  04-01-10  02:47 Narda Safety Test Solutions";
string Date = Regex.Match(Temp, "[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{2}").Value;
string time = Regex.Match(Temp, "[0-9]{2}:[0-9]{2}").Value;
```

Fiddle here : https://dotnetfiddle.net/5ULhJS

Comment: I guess we can make it `string x = Regex.Match(...).Value` for simplicity to the OP.

Comment: @JuliánUrbano : Sure thing. Done!